# How can i pass specific values from one sheet to another sheet based on specific criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel Workbook with two Sheets. In one sheet I have these values:

[image: Sheet1]

and in the second sheet i have this values:

[image: Sheet2]

What I want is that in the **Sheet2** the cell E to have values of *Prognose* from **Sheet1** where **"Motor"** of *module_team* and **"OM470"** of series gives values based on *Datum_produktion* in the **Sheet2**.

The formula that I have tried till now is this but it doesn't seem to give me the values that I need.

`=IF(Tabelle1!B2="Motor";VLOOKUP(A2;Tabelle1!$F:$H;2;FALSE);VLOOKUP(A2;Tabelle1!$F:$H;2;FALSE))`

I also tried this formula but it gives me the #NUM! value.

`=INDEX(Tabelle1!$G:$G; AGGREGATE(15; 7; ROW($2:$500)/((Tabelle1!$D$1:$D$500=E$1)*(Tabelle1!$F$1:$F$500=$A2)*(Tabelle1!$B$1:$B$500="Motor")); 1))`

I adjusted the Settings in the Calculation part by checking the **Enable Iterative** but still it doesnt work.

An exmaple how should look in the **Motor** under OM470 sheet.

[image: Motor sheet]

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Yes they are consistent..

Comment: Please confirm what is the data format in `series`, `Datum_Produktion` and `Prognose`? Also why is there `0` in front of the numbers in `Prognose`?

Comment: *Series* and *Prognose* has the **General Format** and the *Datum_produktion** has **Date** Format with sample **(01.06.2017)**.
the first day of the month for each series *Prognose* is **0**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use **SUMPRODUCT** to solve your issue:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Nr_module_team=100)*(series="OM470")*(Datum_Produktion=I2)*Prognose)
```

I have used a few **named ranges** in my formula:

- `Nr_module_team`: Column A on your Sheet1;
- `series`: Column D on your Sheet1;
- `Datum_Produktion`: Column F on your Sheet1;
- `Prognose`: Column G on your Sheet1,

You can replace these named ranges with actual cell references.

[image: SUMPRODUCT]

Cheers :)

Comment: It helped me a lot ! i used different way to implement it and it works now.
Thank you for the hints.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
=IF(Tabelle1!B2="Motor";VLOOKUP(A2;Tabelle1!$F:$H;2;FALSE);VLOOKUP(A2;Tabelle1!$F:$H;2;FALSE))
```

checks if B2 = 'Motor' in Sheet 1 
**if so**, it looks up the date in Col A (Sheet 2) and returns the value from Sheet 1 in the row matching the Col A value 
**if not**, it does exactly the same thing.

If you want 0 or null (I'll assume 0) in the cells where the value in Sheet1!B2 is not 'Motor', change your lookup formula to:

```
=IF(Tabelle1!B2="Motor";VLOOKUP(A2;Tabelle1!$F:$H;2;FALSE);0)
```

Change the '0' to "" if you want an empty cell.

Based on your comment (you want the figure when the value in Col B = 'Motor' and the value in Col D = 'OM473') change the formula to:

```
=IF(AND(Tabelle1!B2="Motor", Tabelle1!D2="OM473"); VLOOKUP(A2; Tabelle1!$F:$H; 2; FALSE); 0)
```

Comment: Well it should give me only the *Motor* values, and if there is no *Motor* values which is unlikely then **0** or **null** or just empty cell.

Comment: But i need all the values of  **OM470** that are in **Motor** and *Vlookup* doesn't give me that.

Comment: >>if there is no *Motor* values which is unlikely?  You have 'GATS', 'Getriebe', 'Achse' in column B of Sheet 1.  All these rows won't run the VLOOKUP

Comment: Yeah thats why i need that *vlookup* just **ingore** them and  look at **Motor** values.
Sorry

Comment: So the logic could be like this but i dont know how to do it :

````=IF(Tabelle1!B17="Motor";Tabelle1!D17="OM473";VLOOKUP(A17;Tabelle1!$F:$Y;2;))````

Comment: so you only want a result if B17 = Motor and D17 = 'OM473'?  I'll add that to the formula

Comment: Yes exactly, I want the *Progrnose* values from B17=Motor / D17=OM473 to be in the column of **sheet2** under column Name *OM473*

Comment: It doesnt allow me to run the Code with *Comma* between the **Tabelle1!B2="Motor" **,** **Tabelle1!D2="OM473")** and when i replace comma with **;** it gives me all the values 0.

Comment: The comma / semicolon issue depends on international versions.  My formula should use a semicolon (fixed).  I'm now getting confused whether you want OM473 or OM470 (or maybe all the OM### values).  Can you mock up what you want the 'Motor' sheet to look like with say, the first 10 rows in the OM470 column filled in?

Comment: i uploaded a picture with an  example. *Example sheet*

Comment: where did u upload it?

Comment: I uploaded where you answered the question, under the line of Code ````=IF(AND(Tabelle1!B2="Motor", Tabelle1!D2="OM473"); VLOOKUP(A2; Tabelle1!$F:$H; 2; FALSE); 0)````

Comment: Ah, ok, in my answer.  It's probably better to add it to your question.

Comment: Sorry, i am new in Stackoverflow :S